# Can anyone explain me in depth about variables?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, variables

Hi I have been recently learning about variables and values in Kotlin. But after reading many articles and watching endless hours of tutorials I still can't comprehend it. I was hoping someone could enlighten me.

I understand that a value is inmutable and this implies it does not change. and a variable it does. But what I don't get is this :

```
fun main () {

    Var myFirstVariable= "Hello"

    println(myFirstVariable) 

    myFirstVariable = "Nice to meet you"

    println(myFirstVariable)

}
```

Now my question is why would someone need a variable if the first variable is cancelled by the second value of the assigned variable ?

I just could use a value and save myself some time, and  code.

Can somebody clarify this to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit weird but i will explain with just 1 example...

Imagine, you have a **score** variable. Whenever your player move, you will increase this, right? Maybe we need that in this case? Also if you want, you can do **static** variables, example "PlayerSpeed = 100"; like this, you can make this variable static, so i think you can use it whenever you need it.